# Prove product of coefficients of is absolutely convergent in a Hilbert Space Kreyszig 3.5 #6

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

This is from Kreyszig's Functional analysis text chapter 3.6 problem 6. I feel like the proof is just an application of theorems presented in this chapter. There is a theorem stating the coefficients $a_j$ and $b_j$ for x and y are absolutely convergent series due to the fact that $e_j$ is an orthonormal sequence. Also we know that the complex conjugate of any scalar has the same norm so that also forms a convergent series. Now the sum of two absolutely convergent series is also absolutely convergent and by another lemma, the series is convergent in the Hilbert space.

I'm not sure if there was any logical mistakes, but I think that suffice to prove this result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what those lemmas which you mentioned in the question are. I will give an answer below.

> **Question.** Let $(e_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space $H$. Show that if \begin{equation}   x= \sum_{j=1}^\infty
>   \alpha_j e_j , \qquad y= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \beta_j e_j,   
>   \end{equation} then  \begin{equation} \langle x,y \rangle =
>   \sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j \overline{\beta}_j, \end{equation} the
> series being absolutely convergent.

***Proof.*** Using the fact that the inner product $\langle\, \cdot \, ,\, \cdot\, \rangle$ is continuous, we deduce that
\begin{align*}
\langle x,y\rangle &= \left\langle  \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i, \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j e_j\right\rangle\\
&= \lim_{n \to\infty}  \left\langle   \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i,  \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j e_j\right\rangle\\
&=\lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left\langle  \alpha_ie_i,\beta_je_j\right\rangle\\
&= \lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \langle \alpha_j e_j, \beta_j e_j\rangle\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j \overline{\beta}_j.
\end{align*}

Now we prove that the series is actually absolutely convergent.
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left| \alpha_j \overline{\beta}_j\right| &=   \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left| \alpha_j\right|\cdot \left| \overline{\beta}_j\right| \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left| \langle x,e_j\rangle\right| \cdot \left|  \langle e_j ,y\rangle \right| \quad (\text{also by the continuity of the inner product})\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n \left| \langle x,e_j\rangle\right| \cdot \left| \langle e_j ,y\rangle \right|\\
&\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n \left|\langle x,e_j\rangle\right|^2 \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n \left|\langle e_j,y\rangle \right|^2 \quad (\text{by Cauchy--Schwarz inequality in $\mathbb{R}$})\\
&=  \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|\langle x,e_j\rangle\right|^2 \cdot \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left|\langle e_j,y\rangle \right|^2  \\
& \leq \|x\|^2 \cdot \|y\|^2 \quad (\text{by Bessel's inequality})\\
& <\infty.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have completed our proof.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You know the form of $\alpha_j,\beta_j$. Use Bessel's inequality.

Also, the coefficients $\alpha_j, \beta_j$ do NOT (necessarily) form an absolutely convergent series; their squares on the other hand...

Comment: yes the theorem states that the squares of the coefficient forms an absolutely convergent series, but if that is the case, then so would the sum of the non squared series right? Because the squared series must be larger than the non squared series. That is what I thought.

Comment: @William: You have it the wrong way: since the general term goes to zero, eventually we'll have $|\alpha_j|^2\leq |\alpha_j|$.